# FullSimplify doesn't know simplify an obvious expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
expr=(2 (x1-x3) (x2^2-x3^2+y2^2-y3^2)+2 (x2-x3) (-x1^2+x3^2-y1^2+y3^2))/
  (4 (x3 (y1-y2)+x1 (y2-y3)+x2 (-y1+y3)));

Through[{Simplify,FullSimplify,Cancel}[expr]]
```

Obvious, this algebraic expression could be cancel common factors `2`, 
I have tried `Simplify`, `FullSimplify` and `Cancel`, `FullSimplify`  doesn't know simplify it, `Cancel` make it more complicated.
[image]

Comment: I usually use `Factor` in such situations.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
expr // Together
```

which eleminates Factor `2`